# Не отрабатывает обратное значение

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var rotate = 0;

  function CalculateTotal() {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        rotate = rotate + 10;

        $('.bull').css({
          "transform": "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)"
        });
      }
    });
    $("#price").html(total);
  }

  $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    total = 0;
    CalculateTotal();
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="our-form">
  <div>
    <label for="item-1">HTML 5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item-1" id="item-1" value="1000">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="item-2">SASS</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item-2" id="item-2" value="1000">
  </div>
</form>
<span id="price"></span>

<img class="bull" src=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzG9X.png" alt="">
```

В общем по изменению инпута я хочу возвращать значение rotate картинки обратно, также если выбрано 2 и более, то возвращать только на ту единицу, которая не выбрана. else прописываю - ничего не работает

Answer (score 0):

А зачем обнулять total перед каждым кликом? А change не нужно дополнительно добавлять trigger - оно и без этого срабатывает. Перебирать все чекбоксы тоже не обязательно - достаточно передать в качестве аргумента функции только текущий чекбокс. И проверять - если он чекнут - плюсовать значения, если нет - вычесть:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var rotate = 0;

  $("input:checkbox").on('change', function() {
    calculateTotal(this);
  });

  function calculateTotal(checkbox) {
    var checked = checkbox.checked;
    var val = +checkbox.value;
    total = checked ? total + val : total - val;
    rotate = checked ? rotate + 45 : rotate - 45;

    $('.bull').css({"transform": "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)"});
    $("#price").text(total);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="our-form">
  <div>
    <label for="item-1">HTML 5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item-1" id="item-1" value="1000">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="item-2">SASS</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item-2" id="item-2" value="1000">
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<img class="bull" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzG9X.png" alt="">
<span id="price"></span>
```

• value всё равно вы сами вводите в HTML, а не пользователь. Тогда можно не перестраховаться через parseFloat, а просто поставить плюсик перед полученным value, и оно превратится в число.

• Принято начинать название функции с заглавной буквы, если она является конструктором. А здесь функция не такая)

Comment: Отлично!) и код меньше стал, и заработало как нужно. Еще пару моментов, надеюсь, сам доштрихую - появление числа анимированно как счетчик и нижнюю координату рисунка неподвижно оставить и тоже плавно двигать - и все. Спасибо)